# PHP Foreach loop - Search values of an array in a different array and do math if exists

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a MySQL database with a table which has two different values inside a `AppliedNo` column. `AppliedNo` values with A1 `id` is `1,2,15,92,132` and with A2 `id` is `2,99,120,132,313`. My goal is write a piece of PHP code that can evaluates the existence of each A2 members in A1  and then if it exists, add +1 to `$no`. For example, the `calNumbers($A1, $A2)` should iterate the values as follows:

A1 => `1,2,15,92,132`

A2 => `2,99,120,132,313`

`2`            exists in `1,2,15,92,132` => `$no=0+1=+1`

`99`  does not exists in `1,2,15,92,132` => `$no=+1`

`120` does not exists in `1,2,15,92,132` => `$no=+1`

`132`          exists in `1,2,15,92,132` => `$no=+1+1=+2`

`313` does not exists in `1,2,15,92,132` => `$no=+2`

```
public static function calNumbers($A1, $A2)
{
    $value1 = Database::getValues($A1);
    $value2 = Database::getValues($A2);
    $no = "0";
    foreach ($value2 as $number) {
        if (array_key_exists($number, $value1)) {
            $no++;
        } else {
            $no;
        }
    }
    return $no;
}
```

Comment: Do it via mysql. `UPDATE a2 SET no = no +1 WHERE id in(select id from a1);`

Comment: Yes doing this procedure via mysql is the best solution for this.

Comment: @sectus, thanks for your comment, would you please update the code if possible? thanks

Comment: How about union on 2 arrays? The count of union will give u the desired results... else try doing a foreach loop of the second array and search that element in the first one by doing an in_array

Comment: @NinadAjnikar, As you see, I personally like to follow your method, but I think the foreach loop is not correct, would you please fix the code and submit your answer? thanks

Comment: Now you're overwriting `$value1` and `$value2` with empty arrays; that would obviously not give the correct results.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, do I need to explode the comma and then insert the data into the foreach loop? I think PHP considers `1,2,15,92,132` from MySQL as a string, right?

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I exploded the comma, and worked well,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value1 = array(1,2,15,92,132);
$value2 = array( 2,99,120,132,313 );
var_dump( count( array_intersect( $value1,$value2 ) ) );
```

Another answer:

```
$value1 = array(1,2,15,92,132);
$value2 = array( 2,99,120,132,313 );
$total = 0;
foreach( $value2 as $value ) {
    if( true == in_array( $value, $value1 ) ) {
        echo 'No:'. $value;
        $total += $value;
    }
}

echo 'Total:'. $total;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to have each element of `$value1` in `$value2` to be iterated separately inside a `foreach` loop, how can I integrate the foreach loop with your answer?

Comment: $value1 = array(1,2,15,92,132);
    $value2 = array( 2,99,120,132,313 );
    $total = 0;
    foreach( $value2 as $value ) {
  if( true == in_array( $value, $value1 ) ) {
   echo 'No:'. $value;
   $total += $value;
  }
 }
 
 echo 'Total:'. $total;

Comment: In my case, I just used `$total ++;` instead of `$total += $value;`, thanks

Comment: I didn't knew what you wanted to achieve!